# Spring MVC: How to create single instance of object while deserialization JSON string containing duplicate object definitions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize JSON string containing duplicate definitions into java objects using Spring MVC.
The requirement is to have a single instance of an object created for these duplicate definitions instead of creating duplicate objects with the same content.

Example class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Example implements Serializable {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

JSON String:

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1"
  }
]
```

The output that I'm getting:

```
 ExampleList=[
    Example@151c632a, 
    Example@5051613a, 
    Example@6212cffd
    ]
```

There are three individual objects created.

The output I desire is:

```
 ExampleList=[
    Example@1eda78db, 
    Example@1eda78db, 
    Example@68a94d19
    ]
```

Where there are 2 objects created (1eda78db & 68a94d19) instead of 3.

I saw a similar post which takes about implementing `readResolve()` but is there any easy way to do this which is less memory intrinsic?
[How can I link two Java serialised objects back together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717166/how-can-i-link-two-java-serialised-objects-back-together#)

Here's the use-case that I want to solve.
The object `accountT` and `objId0` in `accountNameinfoTList` are same.
I want to modify the object `accountT` and want to see that getting reflected in `objId0`

```
{
  "accountT": {
    "poidId0": 200,
    "poidDb": 1,
    "poidType": "/account",
    "poidRev": 10
  },
  "accountNameinfoTList": [
    {
      "id": {
        "recId": 1
      },
      "objId0": {
        "poidId0": 200,
        "poidDb": 1,
        "poidType": "/account",
        "poidRev": 10
      },
      "address": "2632 Marine Way",
      "canonCompany": "child corp",
      "canonCountry": "GB",
      "city": "Elstree",
      "company": "Child Corp"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help others.
I was able to work around this issue by leveraging the `@JsonCreator`

I created a static method, `createExample` by passing the values using `@ JsonProperty`

```
public class Example implements Serializable {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonValue
    private String a;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonValue
    private String b;
    public Example() {
    }
    @JsonCreator
    public static Example createExample(@JsonProperty("a") String a,
                                        @JsonProperty("b") String b) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.a = a;
        example.b = b;
        return (Example) ReferenceMap.findOriginalObject(example);
    }
}
```

With ReferenceMap holding the details in the WeakHashMap!

```
public class ReferenceMap {
    public static final String KEY_WEAK_REFERENCE_MAP = "weakReferenceMap";

    public static Object findOriginalObject(Object object) {
        Map<Object, Reference<Object>> weakReferenceMap = fetchWeakReferenceMapFromServletRequest();
        WeakReference<Object> originalReference = (WeakReference<Object>) weakReferenceMap.get(object);
        Object originalObject = originalReference == null ? null : originalReference.get();
        if (originalObject == null) {
            originalObject = object;
            weakReferenceMap.put(originalObject, new WeakReference<>(originalObject));
        }
        return originalObject;
    }

    private static Map<Object, Reference<Object>> fetchWeakReferenceMapFromServletRequest() {
        HttpServletRequest
                request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
        Object requestAttribute = request.getAttribute(KEY_WEAK_REFERENCE_MAP);
        if (requestAttribute == null) {
            Map<Object, Reference<Object>> weakReferenceMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
            requestAttribute = weakReferenceMap;
            request.setAttribute(KEY_WEAK_REFERENCE_MAP, weakReferenceMap);
        }
        return (Map<Object, Reference<Object>>) requestAttribute;
    }
}
```

With this, I'm sure of always getting an existing instance instead of creating a new one.

**UPDATE**
Saving the WeakHashMap in the ServletRequestAttributes instead of JVM's heap.